Vite HMR not Working on Docker WordPress Nginx Reverse Proxy
I want to reverse proxy between Nginx and Vite in my local WordPress theme development inside docker environtment. My setup here is working in production, otherwise it's not working in development. It returns 404 for https://localhost.test/main.js and I can not watch any file changes.
Project Structure
project-dir/
        - certs/
            - localhost.test.pem
            - localhost.test-key.pem
        - config/
            - nginx.conf
            - default.conf
        - logs/
        - mytheme/
            - index.php
            - functions.php
            - style.css
            - vite.config.js
            - package.json
        - Dockerfile
        - docker-compose.yml

/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost.test

Dockerfile
FROM mariadb:latest AS db

FROM wordpress:6.5.2-php8.3-fpm-alpine as wp

RUN set -ex; \
    apk --no-cache add sudo \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

VOLUME /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
USER www-data

FROM nginx:alpine3.19 as server
RUN set -x; \
    addgroup -g 1000 -S www-data ; \
    adduser -u 1000 -D -S -G www-data www-data && exit 0 ; exit 1

RUN set -eux; \
    apk update && apk --no-cache add \
    curl \
    && addgroup www-data nginx \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs
COPY ./config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./config/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

VOLUME /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    build:
      target: db
    image: localhost/db
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./logs/sql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wp_net

  wp:
    build:
      target: wp
    image: localhost/wp
    container_name: wp
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
        define( 'WP_HOME','https://localhost.test' );
        define( 'WP_SITEURL','https://localhost.test' );
        define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
        define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
        define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
        define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );
        define( 'IS_VITE_DEVELOPMENT', true );
    volumes:
      - wp_data:/var/www/html
      - ./mytheme:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/mytheme
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - wp_net

  nginx:
    build:
      target: server
    image: localhost/nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - wp_data:/var/www/html:ro
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      - ./mytheme:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/mytheme:ro
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - wp
    networks:
      wp_net:
        aliases:
          - localhost.test
volumes:
  wp_data:

networks:
  wp_net:

nginx.conf
user    www-data;
worker_processes  1;

pid     /var/run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include     /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                            '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                            '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                            '$request_time $upstream_response_time $pipe $upstream_cache_status';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_proxied any;

    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

default.conf
upstream wp {
    server wp:9000;
}

server {
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    http2 on;

    server_name localhost.test;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;

    sendfile off;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/wp.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/wp.error.log;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;

    ssl_protocols             TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers               "ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;";

    # generated with mkcert
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/localhost.test.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/localhost.test-key.pem;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass wp;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}

functions.php
<?php
define('DIST_URI', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist');
define('DIST_PATH', get_template_directory() . '/dist');

define('IS_VITE_DEVELOPMENT', true);

define('VITE_SERVER', 'https://localhost.test');
define('VITE_ENTRY_POINT', '/main.js');

// enqueue hook
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    
    if (defined('IS_VITE_DEVELOPMENT') && IS_VITE_DEVELOPMENT === true) {

        // This is the problem.
        function vite_head_module_hook() {
            echo '<script type="module" crossorigin src="'. VITE_SERVER . VITE_ENTRY_POINT . '"></script>';
        }

        add_action( 'wp_head', 'vite_head_module_hook' );      

    } else {
        // For production.
    }
});

package.json
{
  "name": "mytheme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development vite",
    "build": "rimraf dist && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.5",
    "vite": "^5.2.11"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.2.1"
}

vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { resolve } from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        {
            handleHotUpdate({ file, server }) {
                if (file.endsWith('.php')) {
                    server.ws.send({ type: 'full-reload', path: '*' });
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    root: '',
    base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
        ? '/'
        : '/dist/',
    build: {
        outDir: resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        emptyOutDir: true,
        manifest: true,
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                main: resolve(__dirname + '/main.js')
            },
        }
    },
    server: {
        host: true,
        cors: true,
        strictPort: true,
        hmr: {
          host: "localhost.test",
        }, 
    }
})

Vite use https://localhost:5137 to serve HMR. However, I want to use https://localhost.test to watch file changes. How to achive that in good way?
Any help would be appreciated.

I can figure out now. Only need to touch two files: functions.php and vite.config.js.
In the functions.php, change the value from:
define('VITE_SERVER', 'https://localhost.test');

to:
define('VITE_SERVER', 'http://localhost:5137'); // Adjust to your vite port.

In vite.config.js, change server block into:
server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    strictPort: true,
    proxy: {
      '/wp-content/**': {
        target: 'https://localhost.test', // Adjust to your domain.
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/wp-content/, '.') // Dot means current directory or adjust to your need.
      }
    }
}

Hope it can help anyone. Thanks.
